# (Go) How to use toml files?

Tags: go, toml

As title, I want to know how to use toml files from golang.

Before that, I show my toml examples. Is it right?

```
[datatitle]
enable = true
userids = [
    "12345", "67890"
]
    [datatitle.12345]
    prop1 = 30
    prop2 = 10

    [datatitle.67890]
    prop1 = 30
    prop2 = 10
```

And then, I want to set these data as type of struct.

As a result I want to access child element as below.

```
datatitle["12345"].prop1
datatitle["67890"].prop2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try something ?
Show us dome Code :)

Comment: https://godoc.org/?q=toml

Comment: I'm so sorry.
There was a shortage of explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First get BurntSushi's toml parser:

`go get github.com/BurntSushi/toml`

BurntSushi parses toml and maps it to structs, which is what you want.

Then execute the following example and learn from it:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/BurntSushi/toml"
    "log"
)

var tomlData = `title = "config"
[feature1]
enable = true
userids = [
  "12345", "67890"
]

[feature2]
enable = false`

type feature1 struct {
    Enable  bool
    Userids []string
}

type feature2 struct {
    Enable bool
}

type tomlConfig struct {
    Title string
    F1    feature1 `toml:"feature1"`
    F2    feature2 `toml:"feature2"`
}

func main() {
    var conf tomlConfig
    if _, err := toml.Decode(tomlData, &conf); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("title: %s", conf.Title)
    log.Printf("Feature 1: %#v", conf.F1)
    log.Printf("Feature 2: %#v", conf.F2)
}
```

Notice the `tomlData` and how it maps to the `tomlConfig` struct.

See more examples at https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml

Comment: Thanks for good advises!
I'll try that and then feedback you!

Comment: @Harry I fixed the example, it didn't run well, and as far as I can see, BurnSushi/toml doesn't support dots in the category, like your question shows. If you must have those dots, try another library like https://github.com/pelletier/go-toml

Comment: It was salved for your help!!
I feedback my code when I'm free.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Harry Glad I could help, and welcome to Stack Overflow :-). If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hello. I'm sorry to tell it, but the BurntSushi/toml is officially unmaintained anymore https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml/commit/ea60c4def909bde529d41a7e0674e31eba751da3

Answer (score 6):

A small update for the year 2019 - there is now newer alternative to [BurntSushi/toml](https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml) with a bit richer API to work with **.toml** files:

[pelletier/go-toml](https://github.com/pelletier/go-toml) (and [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/pelletier/go-toml))

For example having `config.toml` file (or in memory):

```
[postgres]
user = "pelletier"
password = "mypassword"
```

apart from regular marshal and unmarshal of the entire thing into predefined structure (which you can see in the accepted answer) with [pelletier/go-toml](https://github.com/pelletier/go-toml) you can also query individual values like this:

```
config, err := toml.LoadFile("config.toml")

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error ", err.Error())
} else {

    // retrieve data directly

    directUser := config.Get("postgres.user").(string)
    directPassword := config.Get("postgres.password").(string)
    fmt.Println("User is", directUser, " and password is", directPassword)

    // or using an intermediate object

    configTree := config.Get("postgres").(*toml.Tree)
    user := configTree.Get("user").(string)
    password := configTree.Get("password").(string)
    fmt.Println("User is", user, " and password is", password)

    // show where elements are in the file

    fmt.Printf("User position: %v\n", configTree.GetPosition("user"))
    fmt.Printf("Password position: %v\n", configTree.GetPosition("password"))

    // use a query to gather elements without walking the tree

    q, _ := query.Compile("$..[user,password]")
    results := q.Execute(config)
    for ii, item := range results.Values() {
        fmt.Println("Query result %d: %v", ii, item)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

<s>There is also [spf13/viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) that works with .toml config files (among other supported formats), but it might be a bit overkill in many cases.</s>

**UPDATE 2**

Viper is not really an [alternative](https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/master/viper.go#L43) (credits to [@GoForth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13383986/goforth)).

Comment: Actually Viper uses pelletier's library: https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/master/viper.go#L43

Comment: @GoForth that is good to know, thanks! I guess then we can strike viper out from the question :)

Comment: Sure, I was actually surprised myself when I looked into it.  I still think Viper is cool as it's an all-in-one solution I just wanted to point that out in case someone is looking only for TOML.

Answer (score 3):

This issue was solved using recommended pkg BurntSushi/toml!!
I did as below and it's part of code.

[toml example]

```
[title]
enable = true
[title.clientinfo.12345]
distance = 30
some_id = 6
```

[Golang example]

```
type TitleClientInfo struct {
    Distance int    `toml:"distance"`
    SomeId  int     `toml:"some_id"`
}

type Config struct {
    Enable     bool     `toml:"enable"`
    ClientInfo map[string]TitleClientInfo `toml:"clientinfo"`
}

var config Config
_, err := toml.Decode(string(d), &config)
```

And then, it can be used as I expected.

```
config.ClientInfo[12345].Distance
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With solution ***Viper*** you can use a configuration file in JSON, TOML, YAML, HCL, INI and others properties formats.

Create file:

```
./config.toml
```

First import:

```
import (config "github.com/spf13/viper")
```

Initialize:

```
config.SetConfigName("config")
config.AddConfigPath(".")
err := config.ReadInConfig()
if err != nil {             
    log.Println("ERROR", err.Error())
}
```

And get the value:

```
config.GetString("datatitle.12345.prop1")
config.Get("datatitle.12345.prop1").(int32)
```

Doc.: https://github.com/spf13/viper

e.g.: https://repl.it/@DarlanD/Viper-Examples#main.go

Answer (score 0):

I am using [spf13/viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper)

### 3rd packages

| Status | Project | Starts | Forks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alive | [spf13/viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) | [image: stars] | [image: stars] |
| Alive | [BurntSushi/toml](https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml#this-project-is-unmaintained) | [image: stars] | [image: stars] |

### usage of viper

I tried to use a table to put the code and the contents of the configuration file together, but obviously, the editing did not match the final result, so I put the image up in the hope that it would make it easier for you to compare

[image]

---

```golang
package main
import (
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
    "log"
    "os"
)
func main() {
    check := func(err error) {
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    myConfigPath := "test_config.toml"
    fh, err := os.OpenFile(myConfigPath, os.O_RDWR, 0666)
    check(err)
    viper.SetConfigType("toml") // do not ignore
    err = viper.ReadConfig(fh)
    check(err)

    // Read
    log.Printf("%#v", viper.GetString("title"))                 // "my config"
    log.Printf("%#v", viper.GetString("DataTitle.12345.prop1")) // "30"
    log.Printf("%#v", viper.GetString("dataTitle.12345.prop1")) // "30"  // case-insensitive
    log.Printf("%#v", viper.GetInt("DataTitle.12345.prop1"))    // 30
    log.Printf("%#v", viper.GetIntSlice("feature1.userids"))    // []int{456, 789}

    // Write
    viper.Set("database", "newuser")
    viper.Set("owner.name", "Carson")
    viper.Set("feature1.userids", []int{111, 222}) // overwrite
    err = viper.WriteConfigAs(myConfigPath)
    check(err)
}
```

```
title = "my config"

[datatitle]

  [datatitle.12345]
    prop1 = 30

[feature1]
  userids = [456,789]
```




```
database = "newuser"  # New
title = "my config"

[datatitle]

  [datatitle.12345]
    prop1 = 30

[feature1]
  userids = [111,222]  # Update

[owner]  # New
  name = "Carson"
```

Comment: BurntSushi/toml has had a new maintainer recently https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml/issues/272 it is not unmaitained anymore

Comment: Hi @mh-cbon, thank you for the reminder.  [Unmaintained is create on 2020-10-18 by Andrew Gallant](https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml/blob/ea60c4def909bde529d41a7e0674e31eba751da3/README.md). 

It has been [removed by Martin Tournoij on 2021-06-08](https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml/commit/0179a136e5e6f2a56#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this [1] go-toml library.

It works great for my uses. I wrote this [2] go util to deal with containerd config.toml file using go-toml

[1]https://github.com/pelletier/go-toml

[2]https://github.com/prakashmirji/toml-configer

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.